# Repair of application (msi) fails but normal installation is successfull

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer, iis-6, repair

have web setup project created by VS 2010, when i setup this project all works fine, but when i check "repair" option i get error during installation.

MSI log file

```
Running process 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe' with parameters ' -norestart -sn ""' silently...
Process Call Result Code: '0' Process Exit Code: '1'.
The error indicates that IIS is in 32 bit mode, while this application is a 64 bit application and thus not compatible.
Trying 32 bit version of 'aspnet_regiis.exe'...
Reading registry value Path from key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0'...
RESULT Path =
Running process 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe' with parameters ' -norestart -sn ""' silently...
Process Call Result Code: '0' Process Exit Code: '1'.
The error indicates that IIS is in 64 bit mode, while this application is a 32 bit application and thus not compatible.
```

I couldnt uderstand why both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of aspnet_regiis not compatible to application?

When i check "setup" not "repair" option, path param is set to my application and setup works fine, so maybe i have to change something in my setup project?

IIS6 is set to 64-bit mode by the way ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you support 32 and 64-bit systems you need separate setups for both.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx

so you'd run the appropriate aspnet exe for the system, that might solve some problems. You haven't said if your setup is x86 or x64, so it's hard to say what the exact issue might be. 32-bit processes cannot call 64-bit Dlls (and vice versa) so the 32-bit aspnet_regiis.exe can't call 64-bit assemblies in a 64-bit IIS, that's probably something to do with it.

That doesn't look like an MSI log file because it hasn't got all the info in there, like the MSI (s) (74:1C) [12:14:05:000]: type of intro, plust suff that would tell you if the call to the ProgramFiles folder is being redirected (look for WIN64DUALFOLDERS in the log).